# Apigee Edge plugin access body

Tags: javascript, apigee

currently I am trying to develop a plugin for the apigee edge microgateway. This plugin should route the request to two different endpoints depending on the body.

I developed the plugin and had some problems regarding the request flow. I can just change the targetHost and targetPath in the onrequest event hanlder. Afterwards the request will got send to the target.

So my problem is now that I need the body at this state. But the body is just accessable in the event handlers afte onrequest. Does anybody know how to change the setting for the microgateway so the reuqest will be send if all the data got received. Or how to access the body just in the onrequest Method.

This is my code currently. The onrequest method have to be deleted. This one changes all incoming request.

````
return {
      onrequest: function (req, res, next) {
        debug('**** onrequest')
        if (req.targetPath.includes(pathPrefix)) {
          req.targetHostname = newTargethost;
          req.targetPath = newUrl;
          req.targetPort = 80;
          debug('new target ' + req.targetHostname)
        }
        next();
      },
      ondata_request: function (req, res, data, next) {
        debug('**** ondata_request')
        var body = JSON.parse(data);
        debug(req.targetHostname)
        if (body.request.id) {
          req.targetHostname = newTargethost;
          req.targetPath = newUrl;
          req.targetPort = 80;
          debug('new target ' + req.targetHostname)
          delete body.request["id"];
          body.request.newId = 3;
        }
        next(null, JSON.stringify(body));
      }
    }; ```
````